# PHP Cache for HTML

Tags: php, caching, memcached

I will be having a bar chart html generated from database results . Cause these chart needs to be refreshed every 5 seconds and there can be 5000 users viewing this chart . I need to cache that bar chart so that I dont have to recreate it everytime user tries to view . I will be recreating that chart again from database every one minute . I am using PHP . Should I use memcache for this purpose ? Are there any other possible options ?

Thanks

Comment: I guess writing it into a file and `include`ing it in subsequent calls isn't fast enough?

Comment: In my case I am doing it every one minute . I am not sure if it will be more I/O over head by doing that . That's reason I was thinking about memcache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcache is the most commonly used and has the best documentation of all other popular solutions.

I would go ahead and use that. It's fairly intuitive as well so it shouldn't take you that long to get up and running.

Comment: I agree, memcached is your answer and you can even set the lifetime to be 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

similiar to @Roman suggestion,
there should be separated process:

one to generate chart, and save the image in memcache (crontab can be used)

the other is usual php script via webserver, which only read memcache and print it out